# Are mini DVI port and DVI port the same thing?

Tags: macbook-pro, dvi, video-adapter

I have an old MacBook and im trying to connect it to a new TV, I have a mini DVI port but can't find adapters for it. Is mini DVI and DVI the same thing? I'm looking for some kind of adapter to HDMI port.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Monoprice sells a Mini-DVI to HDMI adapter (as well as other Mini-DVI adapters). 
http://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=4852

Mini-DVI and DVI are the same electronically, but the mini connector is much smaller and a regular cable will not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Mini DVI and DVI are electrically the same but different physical connectors. Mini-DVI was never a standard, and only was found on Apple hardware until it was replaced with MiniDP. Apple made an adapter that lets you plug in a full-size DVI cable but they haven't produced a computer with this plug in many years so the adapter is no longer available from them, and I don't believe anyone other than Apple ever used the mini-DVI connector so it's not a common cable others would manufacture. You should be able to find an old one online somewhere.

I don't know if there was ever a mini-DVI to HDMI adapter because HDMI wasn't yet common when these laptops were produced, but being electrically identical to standard DVI it should be possible to use a mini-DVI->DVI adapter + DVI->HDMI adapter.

Comment: first place i looked had the exact cable the OP needed

Comment: @samh your link is broken, at least on my phone, but anyway that wasn't really the question.